# Create RTF files from PHP (any better way?)

Tags: php, rtf

Currently I am generating RTF documents using PHPRtfLite. It works perfectly. The only issue is that I have more than 1000 documents with one or more pages in each. To output them via PHPRtfLite, I have to copy paste the data + write formatting details (such as bold, italics or table) into my php file using PHPRtfLite methods. That means a lot of copy and paste. The resulting PHP file is big and messy.

Is there any better / easier way?

Currently I create one PHP file per RTF file.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Best regards,

Tony.

Comment: I havent used PHPRtfLite. But, I think you can rewrite the code of PHPRtfLite to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the PHPRtfLite code, you'll see how to format text to rtf.

Then, put in a loop in your php, and open each file, read the file and output it.
Then close both files and move on to next file

EDIT

@TonyGeorge in that case, load the rtf file

```
$h=fopen("myfile.rtf", "r");
$text=fread($h);
fclose($h);
//Now put the code that handles the rtf conversion, the contents of the rtf will be in $text
```

Comment: Are you kidding, copy paste in php?! no way, just do what pranov suggests. If you had posted the code you might had gotten a solution alreaday.

Comment: Hi Pranav and Melsi, here is the code for one of the document: http://pastebin.com/HUMUz9zJ

The data is not always easy to search and replace. For example, some of them have tables with variable number of rows / columns. Some of the data is conditional. 

I am using CakePHP.

Is there a better way? I think my initial question is not entirely correct because may be you got the idea that the text is read from one file and output into another rtf file.

Comment: @TonyGeorge I've modified my answer, take a look

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you. I still don't understand how to make it work... may be I'm a bit dump :-) Would you please give me a simple example?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I understand reading files and so on. But my question is more like, how will I read an RTF file that is a template and then replace / add / delete values. The most trouble is with table rows and columns.

Comment: @TonyGeorge, that's what regular expressions are for :) Alternatively, you'll have to manually write code to replace the values, e.g. `{companyName}` can be replaced by `$this_company['Company']['name']`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thank you. I know how to use placeholders and later replace them with values. But my template is a bit more complex. One problem is Table Rows and Columns. I don't know how to add or remove them based on conditions. For example, if there are 2 directors, I need 2 rows. If there are 3 I need 3 rows.

Another issue is adding / removing pages based on conditions. Example: if there are 2 directors, I need 2 sets of a document. But the output should be always a single file.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi continuing the above comment: What I want to know is, if there is a faster way to do this than using PHPRtfLite?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, or is there any way for me to combine 2 rtf files using php and output a single document? I am running Linux server with Apache. If yes, I can separate the conditional pages into single templates and combine them as many times as necessary to the main output page.